Ending is different in SuperHOT VR, which has no alternate endings
I watched this YouTube playthrough of SuperHOT VR (last episode in the playthrough). Then I got back into the game and finished it for the first time. And there were huge differences.
Some of the black pyramids you have to grab to get to the next level (for me) were, for him, in places he couldn't possibly reach, and he had to look at them for a certain amount of time instead (the actual levels were all the same though). Not that big of a difference, sure. But then, when he finished the game, he got to see the face of the person talking to him; all I ever got was the voice. And when he grabbed the black pyramid that floated over to him, he got a gun and had to (spoilered for troubling subject matter)

 shoot himself with it. I think he had to do that earlier in the game too, but I don't know when.

When I grabbed the pyramid, it skipped straight to the SuperHOT VR cutscene and stuck me into NG+. No gun in a pyramid.
Apparently, there are no alternate endings to the game.
What happened? Why the differences in playthroughs?

I haven't played the game, but that video is 7 years old, while superhot vr has had regular patches. might be an early version?

@npst pretty big change, considering it’s their entire ending.

Superhot VR was updated on July 21, 2021 to version 1.0.22.1 which removed scenes involving self-harm. To quote the patch notes:

“Skip disturbing scenes” toggle was added in a previous update. Considering sensitive time we’re living in, we can do better than that. You deserve better. All scenes alluding to self harm are now completely removed from the game. These scenes have no place in superhot virtual reality. We regret it took us so long.
We’re commited to shipping this update to all vr platforms.
-superhot team

An article by PCGamer describes two of the removed scenes:

One now-removed scene involved the player motioning the controller like a gun in order to shoot themselves, while another scene had the player jumping off a high-rise building.

As someone who played Superhot VR prior to this update, I can confirm the game's original ending involved the player shooting themself in the head.

When the toggle was implemented, was it set to “No Self Harm Scenes” by default?

@Daemons I cannot remember whether it was on by default.
